# Visualise sets giving some relations on those sets

Tags: plotting, graphics, visualization

I'm not very experienced with wolfram, but I'm searching for a function that can basicly do the following.

Giving some sets $A,B,C$ and some relations for example $B \subset A$,$C\subset B$. I would like wolfram to ask to make some nice diagram of those sets, just by specifing those relations.

I googled a little bit, and I could find things working if I use intersection or unions, for example:

```
WolframAlpha["(A \[Intersection] B) \[Union] (C \[Intersection] D)", \
{{"VennDiagram", 1}, "Content"}]
```

[image]

But I would like to first specify the relations between those sets, and then for example color the the union of B and C. Or maybe things like coloring $A\setminus C$.